# How to add libraries in Eclipse+ROS

Tags: arduino, opencv, rosserial, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am a newer for ROS. I want to compile ROS programs with Eclipse, that includes libraries like openCV, openNI.

Without ROS, I just need to add the library files and paths under linux gcc compiler, which can be set in eclipse project properties.

As I want to publish the computational results to control an arduino board via ROS publisher, I setup the eclipse program with ROS

but I dont know how to add external libraries and setup the compiler, here are what the program needs:

Path:

```
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib
```

lib:

```
-OpenNI
-XnVNite_1_5_2
-glut
-GLEW
-opencv_core
-opencv_highgui
-opencv_imgproc
-opencv_gpu
-opencv_ml
-opencv_video
-opencv_features2d
-opencv_calib3d
-opencv_objdetect
-opencv_contrib
-opencv_legacy
-opencv_flann
```

I cant find related tutorials, how can I compile the program successfully?
Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53310/how-to-add-libraries-in-eclipse+ros/) by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shan333](https://answers.ros.org/users/4043/shan333/) on 2013-01-24**:
Here are the setup steps I followed: http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you followed the tutorial on IDEs you should have an autogenerated Eclipse project. So in this case you have to change the setting related to a build process in relevant `CMakeLists.txt` file, not in Eclipse project settings.

To link additional libraries add `target_link_libraries` directive to your `CMakeLists.txt`:
`rosbuild_add_executable(my_node src/my_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_node GL GLU glut opencv_core opencv_gpu)`

In general, though, you may want to use `find_package` routine -- many of the libraries has relevant "find" modules for CMake. In case there is no such module you can always fall back to `FindPkgConfig` package which is a wrapper for system `pkg-config` utility. Please see [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2